# Dropbox camera upload wrong file name

Tags: bluetooth, files, dropbox

I often take pictures with a mobile phone A and send them via Bluetooth to mobile phone B. On mobile phone B, I move the pictures to the album gallery, such that these pictures are uploaded to my dropbox automatically with dropbox camera upload.

Sometimes, when I do this, the file names of the pictures in my dropbox are incorrect. For example, if I take a picture on 08.05.2022, 11.01.08, then the file name on both devices is IMG_20220508_110108. I sent the file via Bluetooth on 09.05.2022, 10.49.33 and the filename of the picture in my dropbox is 2022-05-09 10.49.33, i.e., the date when the file was sent via Bluetooth. Also, on mobile B in the photo app, the respective picture does appear at 08.05., but at the end, i.e., not sorted correctly. How does this happen and how can I avoid this?

Comment: As far as I know changing the modified file date on Android is not that simply. You should better change settings of your gallery app that uses the exif date like "picture taken on" as sort criteria. Or if it does not support sort by exif date use a different gallery app.

Comment: I created a dummy file named both junk.junk and temp.temp. I ran sha256sum on both files and they had the same checksum. I recommend you take all the files from both phones, run sha256sum or equialent on all files while capturing all the data and save it in a spreadsheet. Use the spredsheet to sort the files by checksum. this will line up all the equivalent filenames. Then create a script to change each filename to the other. In this fashion you will be able to restore all the names correctly.